# MongoDb C# serialize query with take,skip

Tags: c#, mongodb

I know that i can serialize IMongoQuery object to Json and use it in the future, but how can i serialize query with take and skip functions inside? I use official c# mongoDb driver. 
Give me an advice please.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The result from your query is a cursor, and *on that cursor* you call `.skip()` and `.limit()`.

You can serialize a query, but you can't serialize a cursor.

Comment: Thank you ! But can you advice me any workaround for it ? How can i store that data in the query-string ? Can i write it manually ?

Comment: Not if you don't tell what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I have a field in database that stores a queries, earlier that contained only  sql queries with limitation like 'rownumber between top and bottom', but now i need to store mongo queries too.

Comment: You could of course wrap the query in a custom object where you store the additional properties, like `{ queryObject : yourQueryObject, skip: 10, limit:10 }`.